# Javascript Array push updates also cloned object

Tags: javascript

I just noticed something weird with cloning and pushing items. Here's example:

```
let a = { foo: [1,2] };
let b = Object.assign({}, a) // cloning object and getting new reference
a === b // gives false which is what I want
```

now I do `push` on object a:

```
a.foo.push(3)
```

now `a.foo` is `[1,2,3]` but `b.foo` is also `[1,2,3]`

but if I do

```
a.foo = a.foo.concat(4)
```

`a.foo` is `[1,2,3,4]` and `b.foo` is `[1,2,3]`

Question is: Why is that?

Comment: the reason `a.foo` is `[1,2,3,4]` and `b.foo` is `[1,2,3]` is that `concat()` returns a whole new array which will replace `a.foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` does something that is called `shallow cloning` or `shallow copying`. If the source value is a reference to an Object, it only copies that reference value.

Check the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and read **Warning for Deep Clone**.

That is also why a `push` affects both Objects `a` and `b`, because it is in fact the **same** array on which the operation takes place.

The `Array.prototype.concat` method returns a **new** Array Object, which you assign to a.foo (`a.foo = a.foo.concat(4)`), so both foo references will now point to 2 different array objects.

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

[image: Object references]

Answer (score 3):

a.foo and b.foo are pointing to the same reference,but .concat() returns a new array so they now are pointing 2 different array reference

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that?

`Object.assign({}, a)` does shallow copy of your object `a`

```js
const foo = {bar: []}

const baz = Object.assign({}, foo)

console.log(foo.bar === baz.bar)
```

But `Array.prototype.concat` creates new array

```js
const foo = []
const bar = foo.concat()

console.log(foo === bar)
```

Comment: why are you doing foo.bar ===  baz.bar,  explain why foo === baz is false if it is a shalow copy

Comment: @AurA Why would it be true?

Comment: that would be false because it is an object and object structure gets copied in shallow copy but variables point to the same, that is the reason it is returning false here... It is an empty object but still structure gets copied...

Comment: @AurA Doesn't it obvious? Well, atlaest for OP who used this method to do "cloning object and getting new reference". Copy is still a copy though it is shallow.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your case `a.foo` and `b.foo` reference the same array. so a change in one side will affect the other one, and **[`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example)** returns a new array and doesn't alter the first array that's why you got differents results in the second call, as opposed to **[`array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** which will alter the initial array.

**[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example)**:

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

**[array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**:

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

You may also need to read [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript), because `Object.assign()` will just copy the reference to the exisiting objects.

Answer (score 0):

read here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

assign dont do a deep copy, so a.foo and b.foo point to same array so when you push it gets added to same array

but when you do concat it actually returns new array and now both arrays are different

Comment: then why a === b gives false ?

Comment: assume it like so

a = {x : y}
now

b = {}

then b.x = a.x

you should see that a is clearly different but key have same values ..